# how to properly add space and comma in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i have a piece of code in Javascript (using React component).
There is a variable that generates a list of items inside a div. I was asked to add a comma and a space after each item, but not after the last one. I've tried out many ways of adding them (both with and without a  ,) but none seem to be working.

do i need to add a new variable that measures the length of the item list, not to add comma and space after the last one?

also, i think the best way would be to put the comma and space outside of the **span** tags, right?
Please help, JSX is a bit confusing for me.

```
<div className="column" data-test="items">
    {items.map(s => (
        <span key={s.id}>{s.name}</span>
    ))}
</div>
```

would be thankful for any suggestions how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this one:

```
<div className="column" data-test="items">
    {items.map((s, i) => (
        <span key={s.id}>{s.name}{(items.length - 1 !== i) && ', '}</span>
    ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to add a comma a space would be the place where you actually write the `name` in the list using string concatenation. And because you do not want to add the a comma at the last element, you can check the index of the element in the map.

Here is an example from the code you provided

```
<div className="column" data-test="items">
    {items.map((s, index) => (
        <span key={s.id}>{`${s.name}${index !== items.length - 1 ? ', ' : ''}`}</span>
    ))}
</div>
```

The second parameter in the map is the index of the element "s" in the array.

In order to make the check more understandable, I am using ternary operator, however you can use more compact ES6 syntax mentioned in other answer by @Vlad too

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div className="column" data-test="items">
    {items.map(s => (
        <span key={s.id}>{s.name} 
        {index!==index.lengths-1 ? ", "
        : void 0}
        </span>
    ))}
</div>
```